# Can C code be compiled into a static library for any architecture?

Tags: ios, c, objective-c, static-libraries, arm64

I've found a C library I'd like to use in my iOS project.

The library comes with a makefile that will compile the sources into in an `.a` archive. When I run `lipo archs` on the resulting `.a`, `arm64` which is necessary for iOS isn't included.

If I manually throw all of the C sources and headers into my iOS project, everything will compile and link. This however is a clunky solution because it adds hundreds of files to my main project and the library the doesn't seem to be working correctly anyways.

If I try to make a new iOS Static Library project in Xcode and throw all of the C sources and headers in there, I get build errors for every resulting `.o` file resembling: `Building for iOS, but the linked item '<item>.o' was built for macOS`.

Am I trying to do something that isn't possible? What inherently determines the compatible architectures that C sources can be built for?

Comment: If it is just vanilla C it should not be a problem. Those .o files might be leftovers from an earlier compile or accidentally included in the project? Try to clean the project folder and compile again or make sure that when you '...and throw all of the C sources and headers in there ...' that you do so from clean sources ie no compiled stuff or makefiles in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of this is possible, however it is somewhat hard without seeing your code.

Here is a little starter:

```
clang -c library.c -o library.x86_64.o -arch x86_64 // Compile your code to x86_64
clang -c library.c -o library.arm64.o -arch arm64 // Compile your code to arm64
libtool -static -o library.x86_64.a library.x86_64.o // Create a static intel lib
libtool -static -o library.arm64.a library.arm64.o // Create a static arm64 lib
libtool -static -o library.a library.x86_64.a library.arm64.a // Create a universal static lib
```

Without knowing your makefile or your Xcode project, there is not much I can say without doing a very big tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Both dynamic and static libraries reflect the target CPU,just being collections of .o object files from cc -c, but of course you have to have the compiler and direct it to the target CPU.  You do not have to be running the target CPU.  For each target, you need to make specific .o, .a, .so or .dll or whatever they call their object and library files.  There may be cross compatibility between OS for the same CPU.  It depends on the linker and loader of the target OS.  We have seen this with COFF and ELF files for various x86 OS.

Highly optimized code is only fully realized on the right target CPU and possible the right target OS, although it may run well on other compatible systems.